# Reproduce Issue: The http request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'anonymous'

Tags: c#, wcf, http, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I would like to re-produce the wcf issue : **The http request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'anonymous'**

We are using wcf service in our product and we have hosted the wcf service as Windows Service (**Self-Host service**) and this wcf service is being consumed by a small **windows client app**.

Things are working fine in our environment. But, one of our customer reported that they are receiving the error "**The http request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'anonymous'**" while they connect the **client app** from remote client machine.

Here, my question is, can anyone help me to re-generate this issue in our environment, so that we can give perfect fix.

**ServiceApp.config**

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="100" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="24.00:00:00" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>

        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviour" name="WcfServer.CalculatorService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:7000/Test" behaviorConfiguration="MyEndPointBehavior"
          binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
          name="EndPt_Service" contract="WcfServer.ICalculator"/>
      </service>
    </services>
```

**clientapp.config**

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CalBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="100" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="24.00:00:00" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://RemoteServerName:7000/Test" behaviorConfiguration="CalEndPointBehavior"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServer.ICalculator"
         name="EndPt_Calc" bindingConfiguration="CalBinding"/>
    </client>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the msdn forum, I hope this helps you:

Since you have specified Security Mode= none for WsHttpBinding, when it  make request to WCF service , service will try to authenticate client using Aninymous credentials, but in case of different domains this will not work, so try to use  X509 certitifates.

So try to establish a connection between two different domains.